# Static method in generic class causes CA1000 warning

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm working on a library to manage objects (Animals in my sample code). I have a base class named Animal and a generic class named SpecificAnimal. I also have Dog, Cat etc. which are implemented with the SpecificAnimal class.

If a user wants to create a dog, it is as simple as:

```
            var myDog = new Dog()
            {
                Name = "Rover",
                Age = 3
            };
            myDog.Add();
```

The class hierarchy looks like this:

### Animal Class

```
    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public static Animal GetByName(string animalName)
        {
            // Code that can read any kind of animal from a database
            // and create an instance of the correct type 
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static Animal GetById(int animalId)
        {
            // Code that can read any kind of animal from a database
            // and create an instance of the correct type 
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public void Add()
        {
            //  Add this Animal to the database
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            // Update this animal
        }
    }
```

### Generic SpecificAnimal class

```
    public abstract class SpecificAnimal<T> : Animal where T : SpecificAnimal<T>
    {
        public static string Genus { get; protected set; } = String.Empty;

        public new static T GetByName(string animalName)
        {
            // Code that can read an object of type T from a database
            return (T)Animal.GetByName(animalName);
        }

        public new static T GetId(int animalId)
        {
            // Code that can read an object of type T from a database
            return (T)Animal.GetById(animalId);
        }
    }
```

### Dog class

```
    public class Dog : SpecificAnimal<Dog>
    {
        public Dog()
        {
            Genus = "Canis";
        }

        //  Dog specific properties and methods
    }
```

This code is working and (in my opinion) is easy for the consumer of the library to use.

My problem is that the static properties and methods in the SpecificAnimal class generate the warning:

```
CA1000: Do not declare static members on generic types
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1000

The documentation for CA1000 says "Do not suppress..." but, it doesn't suggest a better solution. If I shouldn't have static members in a generic class, what should I be doing?
The documentation says that static methods in a generic type are bad because of this awkward syntax:

```
var myDog = SpecificAnimal<Dog>.GetByName("Rover");
```

I agree but, my users should never do that. Although, I don't know of a way to prevent it.

How can I add static members to a generic class without generating CA1000? How can I protect the SpecificAnimal class so that the user only has access to Dog and Animal?

Comment: I tested your code and didn' t get any warnings

Comment: @Serge, to enable full code analysis you have to add <AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode> to your project file.

Comment: Thank you. But what for? To get tonns of warnings that I don't need.

Comment: Is there a reason you're making this method static instead of making it inherited by the subclasses themselves?  For that matter, your methods are just *asking* for a `InvalidCastException` because you're not verifying that the object you're returning is actually a T before you're casting it.

Comment: @Powerlord, the method is static so you don't have to create an instance of a Dog before you can call GetByName to read another Dog. The real code does appropriate checks so that if someone tries to call Dog.ReadByName() to read a Cat, they get a meaningful exception.

Comment: @Serge: "Thank you. But what for?" - To reproduce the warning reported in this question, per your own request. If you don't see the value of code analysis, that's fine. But that's a bit independent of the question. For those of us who do use and value code analysis, it's useful to understand the basis for these warnings, what the workarounds are, and when it's appropriate to suppress them.

Answer (score 0):

The warning exists because there's risk that the behavior might be different than the programmer expects. However, sometimes it's a useful pattern. I ran into this a few weeks ago when building a library.

Let's look at a more simplified example:

```
void Main()
{
    Baz<string>.Counter++;
    Baz<int>.Counter++;
    Console.WriteLine(Baz<object>.Counter);
}

public abstract class Foo
{
    public static int Counter { get; set; }
}

public class Baz<T> : Foo
{
    
}
```

What is output? It's easy to think the output would be 0 because `Baz<object>` is a different closed generic type than `Baz<string>` or `Baz<int>`. In fact, the output is 2 because both post increment operations affect the same static variable.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the reply but, I think that's a different problem. The code that you posted doesn't generate CA1000 because the Counter property isn't in a generic class.

Answer (score 0):

The property can be rewritten as in the example.

```
public abstract class SpecificAnimal<T> : Animal where T : SpecificAnimal<T>
{
    public virtual string Genus { get; } = String.Empty;
}

public class Dog : SpecificAnimal<Dog>
{
    public override string Genus { get; } = "Canis";
}
```

Note that implementing the static new method does not work in the same way as inheritance.

Comment: The problem with that change is that you have to create an instance of a Dog to find out when the Genus is. That's not the end of the world but, not ideal.